# Not redirect my page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Anyone knows why the button is not redirect back to the other page?Is it because i put 2 functions in the onclick attribute?

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" onclick="submitStatus(); getSyncData(); " ><span class="confirm"></span></a>
```

Comment: What does submitStatus() and getSyncData() do?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that even implies to me that a redirect should happen.

Comment: When I run your code I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: submitStatus is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: getSyncData is not defined`. So that might be your problem.

Comment: Without seeing the content of your JavaScript functions, it’s impossible to tell. There’s nothing inherently wrong with putting two JavaScript function calls into an `onclick` attribute - you can put as much JavaScript as you want in there.

Comment: Is there a page registered in JQM history? If not, data-rel=back won't work. You should post relevant code to let us help you.

Comment: @David JQM has this attribute for pages registered in history using ajax navigation.

Comment: Thx guys i found out that my function was not properly functionning and i'm using a plug-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Javascript, one could use:

```
<form action="page.html" action="post">
  <button type="submit">Go to the page</button>
</form>
```

Or you can use `<a href="page.html">link</a>`